# Order of a dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

Result:

> The number of elements in $D_n$ is $2n$.

I know that for a regular $n$-gon there are $n$ rotational symmetries and $n$ reflectional symmetries but why is it always true. Can anyone please give me any geometrical idea about it?

I feel this idea will help me in proving my original result. I hope I'm correct.

Comment: What's your precise definition of $D_n$?

Comment: It is the set of all symmetries of a regular n gon

Comment: That's not precise at all. What is a symmetry of a regular $n$-gon?

Comment: Can you see how the set of symmetries of a square has 8 elements and the set of symmetries of a regular pentagon has 10? The general case is basically the same as one of those two (depending on whether $n$ is even).

Comment: @Christoph That is a perfectly precise definition of $D_n$! You can ask for more detail, sure, but their definition is perfectly valid and precise.

Comment: (That said, I don't understand the question. Putting a quantified on the $n$, then rewriting it to make it make sense, I get: "I know that *for all $n$* there are $n$ rotational symmetries and $n$ reflectional symmetries of a regular $n$-gon, but why is (this) always true?" Which is a meaningless statement; it is always true because of the "for all". So is the question about trying to get intuition for the result? Or are they just trying to prove it and the quoted paragraph is an "attempt"? I'm not sure.)

Comment: Suppose you have a symmetry of the $n$-gon, and it maps a vertex $A$ to some vertex $X$. Vertex $A$ has two neighbouring vertices. Where could they get mapped to?

Comment: Yes I know it is true for all n.But why?What is the intuition behind it

Comment: Using keywords "geometrical representation dihedral group", and selecting "images" tab, you "harvest" a wealth of information, beginning by an excellent Wikipedia article. What do you want exactly that can not be found there ?

Comment: Brian Conrad's nice notes go into quite a lot of detail on this: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have no doubt on the fact that there are $n$ rotations, that are the rotations of $\frac {2\pi k} n$ $\forall k=0,..,n-1$. About the symmetries we have to distinguish two cases: if $n$ is odd you have an axial symmetry for each segment that goes from the middle point of a side to the opposite vertex, instead if $n$ is even you have an axial symmetry for each couple of opposite sides and a punctual symmetry for each couple of opposite angle. So you have obtained that the dihedral group has at least $2n$ elements, why are we sure that are *all* the elements? Easily an isometry has to send one side to another (this can be done in $n$ possible choices) and then can have two orientation (for example the side $AB$ could go to $CD$ or with $A\to C$ and $B\to D$ or with $A\to D$ and $B\to C$) . So we conclude that dihedral group $D_n$ has $2n$ elements: $n$ rotations and $n$ symmetries.

Comment: [+1] Little detail: simmetry $\to$ symmetry.

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for the ignorance

Comment: Pleasure. Don't feel sorry ! As I appreciate myself when somebody makes me constructive remarks, I do the same !